# How many 2-Legged tokens can a Forge App have active at once?

Tags: autodesk-forge

How many 2-Legged tokens can a Forge App have active at once?

I *think* the answer is 'more than any reasonable person would ask for', but I haven't been able to explicitly confirm this yet.

Comment: Asking because I am working on multi-user applications, and the approach I've been taking is to issue a new 2-legged token for each applicable request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question. I don't think there's any limit to how many access tokens you can have at a single point time but I would definitely not recommend generating new token for each request. Not only is it wasteful but you could also run into [rate limiting quotas](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/developers_guide/rate-limiting/oauth-rate-limits/).

The recommended practice is to generate one or more tokens on the server side (for example, one with `viewables:read` scope for public use, and one with additional scopes for internal use) and only refresh them when they expire.